# JQuery-File-Upload using Signed_URL Google Storage, how to call super class function data.submit() within ajax callback?

Tags: django, ajax, google-cloud-storage, jquery-file-upload, pre-signed-url

I have a fileupload HTML element in my DOM and it currently gets multiple files and calls "add" function for each file. For each file, a signed url is received from an ajax call to the related api. After the succesful ajax call to api, I want to call the data.submit() method of the parent function which is the function in fileupload method as first argument.

How may I be able to access that just after "xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);" ?

The primary inspiration is from this link :http://kevindhawkins.com/blog/django-javascript-uploading-to-google-cloud-storage/

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
dataType: 'json',
sequentialUploads: true,

add: function(e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function(index, file) {
        // pack our data to get signature url
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('filename', file.name);
        formData.append('type', file.type);
        formData.append('size', file.size);

        // Step 3: get our signature URL
        $.ajax({
            url:  '/api/getsignedurl/',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
            },
            context: 'hello',
            data: formData,
        }).done(function (data) {
            // Step 5: got our url, push to GCS
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if ('withCredentials' in xhr) {
                xhr.open("PUT", data.signed_url, true);
            }
            else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== 'undefined') {
                xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                xhr.open("PUT", data.signed_url);
            }
            else {
                xhr = null;
            }

            xhr.onload = () => {
                const status = xhr.status;
                if (status === 200) {
                    //alert("File is uploaded");
                } else {
                }
            };

            xhr.onerror = () => {
            };

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
            //data.submit();

        });
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the $this = $(this) is defined prior to the $.each loop :

```
submit: function(e, data) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each(data.files, function(index, file) { ...
```

Then the following can be used to access the data in the parent function

```
    this.primary_data.headers={'Content-Type': file.type};
    this.primary_data.jqXHR = $this.fileupload('send', this.primary_data);
```